# Decompiled Java from APK - while loops that do nothing

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, apk, decompiling, smali

I decompiled an apk and see many while loops that return immediately only to be followed by other code:

```
while (true){
   return;
   if (!cond1){
     continue;
   }
   if (cond2){
     continue;
   }
}
```

If you wanted to produce this code in a decompile, what Java code would you write to get there?

Note. The decompile process is apktool -> baksmali -> smali -> dex2jar

**EDIT**

I can't actually get at the original Java bytecode from the Android APK (at least I don't know how to).  It may be that my tools are doing a poor reverse-engineering job, but here is what the output of smali is:

```
:goto_8
return-void

.line 40
:sswitch_9
const/4 v0, 0x0

iput v0, p0, Lcom/sec/android/app/camera/command/ContextualTagSelectCommand;->mContextualTag:I

goto :goto_8

.line 44
:sswitch_d
const/4 v0, 0x1

iput v0, p0, Lcom/sec/android/app/camera/command/ContextualTagSelectCommand;->mContextualTag:I

goto :goto_8
```

Which corresponds to:

```
while (true)
{
  return;
  this.mContextualTag = 0;
  continue;
  this.mContextualTag = 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. This is the primary reason I asked the question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: It might have been compiled using another compiler.

Comment: @Error454: can you show us the bytecode or whatever APK uses? Maybe the decompiler got confused?

Comment: It looks like the decompilation of some goto instructions, but without a good inference of the actual Java code. The bigger picture may show that the line `if (!cond1)` is being jumped into from outside.

Comment: The bytecode is pretty much as expected: several gotos to the earlier point. Now look the wider context of the method code, there must be some gotos to :sswitch_9 and :sswitch_d.

Comment: Your first code looks like obfuscated code (Flow Control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bytecode is a fragment of a compiled switch statement. Specifically, it was implemented using the **sparse switch** Dalvik bytecode instruction. You are showing only two switch cases, where both assign to `mContextualTag` and then execute the `return` statement. This `return` is placed at a single point in the program and the switch cases jump to it. The labels `sswitch_9` and `sswitch_d` may be indicating the relative offsets from the `sswitch` instruction itself.

Comment: Yep. This is a switch instruction. The switch data (the cases and targets) will be at the bottom of the method, with a .sparse-switch directive, and there should be a sparse_switch instruction that references that switch data.

Comment: @JesusFreke That agrees with my thinking. I imagined a catch-segment from regular Java, that also occurs at the bottom of the method. The decompiler should have inlined that code into the location of the `sswitch` instruction instead of trying to decompile it as normal program flow.